# Write out text to the console output as an input

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I'm writing a console application with C# and there is a question at the beginning of the program:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to create the config folder? (y/n)");
```

I would like to set a default "y" after this line, so it's enough to the user just to press the Enter.
(or delete it with backspace if (s)he wants "n")

Is this even possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct behavior here should be show something like

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to create the config folder? (y/n) [y]");
```

This tells the user that `y` is the default and by just pressing enter it would be auto selected. I think this would be faster in case a user want to select `n` because then the user don't have to delete `y` and then enter his/ choice.

Consider if the user has to go through multiple question and have to select `n` for all of them. It would be a little annoying.

Simple way to code (just a pseudo-code) it is:

```
boolean selection = true; //false if 'n' is default
if(userinput == 'n') selection = false;
```

If you still want to write a changeable output use:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to create the config folder? (y/n)");
SendKeys.SendWait("y");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You have to fix this: `(y/n) [y]");`. :)

Comment: Can you use `SendKeys` in a console application? It's in the `Forms` namespace.

Comment: Doesn't that send input to the focus? What is the application is minimized or in the background?

Comment: You can try this :). But you can also try the Keyboard.SendKeys function which does the same thing. Also it says 'active window'...

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.Write("y")
```

so Y is on the next line and they just have to press enter.

Comment: Thank you! But with this I'm not able to delete y, if unwanted.

Comment: I tried that before my answer but it doesn't let you delete what was to the left of the cursor.

Comment: @Pistaatortenesz If you have `Console.ReadKey()` after what I posted, you'll only get the backspace key, change that to `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: No, there isn't. There is a Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is a bit strange, in my opinion. What I would do is this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to create the config folder? (Y/N) [Y]");

ConsoleKey optionKey;
do
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    optionKey = key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter ? ConsoleKey.Y : key.Key;
} while (optionKey != ConsoleKey.Y && optionKey != ConsoleKey.N);

Console.WriteLine(optionKey);

if (optionKey != ConsoleKey.N)
{
    // Do your stuff
}
```